SoX reverse method not working on Android
I have tried a few wrappers for the SoX library on Android (https://github.com/pxhbug123, f.e.), and with each of them, I met the same problem: the reverse method resulted in a crash. I can use tempo, noisered, fade, compand - with all of these params I can process my audio files and create new ones. Reverse gives me output like that:
E  can't create temporary file: No such file or directory
A  FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0x7abf7a05a8)
A  Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 29073 (RenderThread), pid 29025 (mmandlibandroid)
A  FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0x7b7c775d30)

An example of a crashing command:
sox input.wav output.wav reverse : restart

All I can say is that the SoX library could not create an output.wav file for some reason. The same command works on OSX properly. Any idea for a workaround, apart from using the different library to revert my audio files?
Debugging https://github.com/pxhbug123 library

TL;DR - it is not a problem with the SoX wrapper. You should select an temporary directory inside internal storage.
https://github.com/pxhbug123/SoxLibInAndroid/issues/4#issuecomment-2102308516
